# Flutter application not working when converted to apk

Tags: database, flutter, mobile-application

I made a small shopping application with flutter using Android studio, it retrieves the items from a database on 000webhost,it works perfectly fine on pc and even on a phone emulator on pc,but if I turn it into an apk file and send it to my phone Nothing happens when I try to login or register a new account, I'm not very familiar with flutter or hosting databases yet as I'm still learning and this is my first project. My guess is it's not connecting to the database, any ideas how to fix it?

I don't know what I should do or what files to attach to the post so let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you forgot to add internet pemission in AndroidManifest.xml file

add this line in AndroidManifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't give access to internet in android manifest